# How to test provider in view model

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-provider

I have a view model that a view uses, i want to write a unit test for one of the functions which contains a provider. The function is something like this

```
Future<String> onSubmit(BuildContext context) async {

PersonProvider personProvider = Provider.of<PersonProvider>(context,listen: false);

String userId = personProvider.user.id;
isLoading = true;
return 'hello';

});}
```

Is there anyway I can test this, or I have to refactor code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your code, if that function is in a ViewModel the problem is that it should not know nothing or as little as possible of the presentation layer. So it should NOT depend on the `BuildContext`, instead pass in the needed dependencies either directly to the function:

```
Future<String> onSubmit(PersonProvider personProvider) async {


String userId = personProvider.user.id;
isLoading = true;
return 'hello';

});}
```

Or inject it to the ViewModel constructor, that way you decouple your viewModel from the UI, and from  `PersonProvider`, which can now be passed as a mock for testing.

If what you are referring to as viewmodel is really just a presenter you could do widget tests and providr a Mock `PersonProvider` implementation to the widget tree.